# Transforming the derivative of $f(x)$ using a table of values

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I have a table that looks like:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
x & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
\hline
f'(x) & 0 & -0.5 & -1 & 0.5 & 1
\end{array}.
$$

And three functions to use to calculate the values of *their derivatives* based on f '(x):

> $a(x) = f(-2x)$
>
> $b(x) = f(x+2)$
>
> $c(x) = f(x^2)$

Apparently the answer is to use the Chain Rule but I don't see how I can without the original function for $f(x)$? A nudge or link in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: Do you need all of the values of the derivatives for $a, b$ and $c$ at $x = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2$?

Comment: If so, it isn't possible. $a'(-2)$ involves $f'(4)$ which isn't given. :(

Comment: Not all of them, I was told about half wouldn't be found, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = f(u)\\
y' = f'(u) u'$
This is the chain rule.

$a(x) = f(-2x)\\
a'(x) = f'(-2x)(-2)\\
a'(-1) = f'(2)(-2) = -2$

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you, those extra lines helped so much